# Why am I getting error 17410 end of data on my rest api when I add a parameter to the query

Tags: rest, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I have ORDS 21 installed in a local 19c oracle database.  I have created a stored procedure to list all the departments from the dept table with a cursor that lists the employees from the emp table.  If I just list all departments and their employees the api works fine, but if I add a parameter to the query to specify which department, I get an error 17410 no data left .

Both queries are backed by plsql stored procedures.  I have created many stored procedures using this same format with parameters and nested cursors before without a problem.

MWE for query that works:

```
create or replace procedure  get_dept
as
    l_cur sys_refcursor;
begin
    open l_cur for
        select d.deptno,d.dname,
        cursor (select e.empno,e.ename
        from emp e
        where e.deptno = d.deptno
        order by e.deptno,e.empno
        ) as employees
        from dept d
        order by d.deptno;

    -- return the resultset in json format
    apex_json.open_object;
    apex_json.write('emps',l_cur);
    apex_json.close_object;
end get_dept; 
/
```

MWE for query that does not work:

```
create or replace procedure  get_dept1
(
    p_dept_no   in  varchar2
) as
    l_cur sys_refcursor;
begin
    open l_cur for
        select d.deptno,d.dname,
        cursor (select e.empno,e.ename
        from emp e
        where e.deptno = d.deptno
        order by e.deptno,e.empno
        ) as employees
        from dept d
        where d.deptno = to_number(p_dept_no)
        order by d.deptno;

    -- return the resultset in json format
    apex_json.open_object;
    apex_json.write('emps',l_cur);
    apex_json.close_object;
end get_dept1;
/
```

Comment: As far as Oracle itself is concerned, the 2nd query works OK (as you already know). (Though, why are you TO_NUMBER-ing the parameter? Pass the number ...) Also, as it is Apex, did you try to run the page in debug mode and see what it says?

Comment: I’m not using Apex to develop my application instead of the Jen application using the rest API‘s served through or RDS

Comment: If you aren't using Apex, why did you use that tag?

Comment: that 17410 message is coming from the database, not  ORDS or APEX

Comment: when i run the sp from an anonymous block: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.OWA_UTIL", line 354
ORA-06512: at "SYS.HTP", line 1362
ORA-06512: at "SYS.HTP", line 1438
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_T_HTP_WRITER", line 39
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_JSON", line 2136
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_JSON", line 2611
ORA-06512: at "HR.GET_DEPT1", line 19
ORA-06512: at line 6